# What does boost::hana::always do more than just "always return its first argument"?

Tags: c++, c++14, overload-resolution, boost-hana, referential-transparency

At the [doc page of `boost::hana::always`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga835970cb25a0c8dc200f1e5f8943538b) I read that

> `always(x)` is a function such that
>
> ```
> always(x)(y...) == x
> ```
>
> for any `y...`.

This makes me think that it shouldn't behave any differently than this lambda: `[](auto const&...){ return false; }`.

However it does. For instance, the following code prints `11`, but if I change the third lambda to `hana::always(false)`, then it prints `00`, revealing that `always` is swallowing any argument.

```
#include <boost/hana/functional/always.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp>
#include <iostream>

auto fun = boost::hana::overload(
        [](int){ return true; },
        [](double){ return true; },
        [](auto const&...){ return false; }
        );

int main() {
    std::cout << fun(1) << fun(1.0) << std::endl;
}
```

- Is this expected?
- If so, why?
- Whether or not is expected, what causes this behavior?

---

By the way, I've just discovered [`boost::hana::overload_linearly`](https://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-functional.html#gaa46de6f618d9f14edb1589b36b6e75ec), which is not an alternative to `boost::hana::overload` in this case (because as much as `always` would not get all the calls, it would be the `[](int){ return true; }` to be greedy), but it's good to know of it.

Comment: With `mutable`, "`[](auto const&...) mutable`" would be a better match than `[](int)` as `fun` is not `const`.

Comment: Yeah, `always` has three overloads for const and reference categories.

Comment: @Jarod42, would you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Related to [c-overload-pattern-call-resolution-with-mutable-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890356/c-overload-pattern-call-resolution-with-mutable-lambda)

Comment: @Jarod42, I would say _that_ is related to _this_ one, based on seniority, ahahah.

Comment: This one is more specific with boost (and the fact that you didn't identify the "`mutable`" overload). That's why I link in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `always` has different overloads (as it handles reference as return value).

so, with a simplified version:

```
template <typename T>
struct my_always
{
     T res;

     template <typename ...&& Ts>
     T& operator ()(Ts&&...) /* mutable */ { return res; } // #1

     template <typename ...&& Ts>
     const T& operator ()(Ts&&...) const { return res; } // #2
};
```

then

```
auto fun = boost::hana::overload(
        my_always<bool>{ false }, // #1 & #2
        [](int){ return true; }   // #3
        );

std::cout << fun(1);
```

Possible overloads are:

- `bool& my_always<bool>::operator ()(int&&)` #1
- `const bool& my_always<bool>::operator ()(int&&) const` #2
- `bool lambda::operator() (int) const` #3

All are [viable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Viable_functions) here, but `#1` is the [best match](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function) (as `fun` is not `const` (and `int` is not better than `int&&`)).

With `const` `fun`, #3 would be the best match (#1 not viable, tie-breaker between #2 and #3 is template status).

Comment: I still have some misunderstanding. You write _All are viable here, but #1 is a better match (as `fun` is not `const`_; I'd say that it's the only non-`const` among the 3 so why do you specify that _`int` is not better than `int&&`_? I think I'm missing something here. Furthermore, would you spend another word on how adding `const` to the function object `fun` interacts with the `const` of the `operator()` of the various arguments to `hana::overload`?

Comment: overload resolution has complex rules to be "intuitive", we have to check all parameters to know which function is the best. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03c18e19e469d9ea) showing ambiguous when constnes is ok, but parameter requires conversion (`void S::print(float) const` versus `void print(int)` for `s.print(4.2f);` one is better for `float` parameter, the other is better for non const `S`, neither is better -> ambiguous call).

Comment: Maybe turning method to free functions (so adding hidden `this` as parameter) might help to see the ambiguity `void f(S&, const S&); void f(const S&, S&); S s; f(s, s); /*Ambiguous*/`.

Comment: Thinking again about it. So the point is that when overloading non-mutable lambdas, the overload resolution is effectively only on their arguments, because they're all uniform with respect to the `this` argument; i.e. wheteher `foo` is `const` or not, the implication in terms of how good the match is is the same on all of them, so the net effect is none. But `always` introduces both `const` and non-`const` `operator()`s, so the goodness of its match in overload resolution has one more player, the `this`.