# C++ overload pattern : call resolution with mutable lambda

Tags: c++, c++17

Considering this well-known C++ pattern :

```cpp
template <class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template <class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>; // clang needs this deduction guide,
                                                           // even in C++20 for some reasons ...
```

I wonder **why** declaring one of the parameter as a mutable lambda changes the override resolution.

*Live example [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vb8jsfE8T)* :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template <class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>; // clang needs this deduction guide,
                                                           // even in C++20 for some reasons ...

auto main() -> int
{
    auto functor_1 = overload{
        [](int &&){
            std::cout << "int\n";
        },
        [](auto &&) {   // making this lambda `mutable` makes deduction mismatch ?
            std::cout << "smthg else\n";
        }
    };
    functor_1(42); // prints `int`

    auto functor_2 = overload{
        [](int &&){
            std::cout << "int\n";
        },
        [](auto &&) mutable {
            std::cout << "smthg else\n";
        }
    };
    functor_2(42); // prints `smth else`
}
```

Comment: Even though this pattern is well-known, I think it'd be beneficial to include a deduction guide (`template <class... Ts> overload(Ts&& ...) -> overload<Ts...>;`), because without it your code does not compile.

Comment: I guess the `void operator()(int&&) const` is a worse match than `template<class T> void operator(T&&)` because the first one is const?

Comment: @Fureeish In fact, only Clang needs the user-defined deduction guide I added to the original question. This is one of the feature of C++20, in opposition to C++17

Comment: Interesting, do you have the name of the paper that proposed that change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With

```
auto functor = overload{
    [](int &&){
        std::cout << "int\n";
    },
    [](auto &&) {
        std::cout << "smthg else\n";
    }
};
functor(42); // prints `int`
```

both closures have `const` qualified `operator()`'s so `int&&` is a better match as it is not a template.

With

```
auto functor = overload{
    [](int &&){
        std::cout << "int\n";
    },
    [](auto &&) mutable {
        std::cout << "smthg else\n";
    }
};
functor(42); // prints `smthg else`
```

Your `auto&&` closure is not `const` qualified anymore, meaning there is no `const` qualification adjustment that needs to happen in order to call it. This makes that overload an identity exact match, while the `int&&` overload needs a `const` qualification adjustment.  The  identity exact match beats out a `const` qualification adjustment exact match per [[tab:over.ics.scs]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/tab:over.ics.scs) so that is why you see the `auto&&` version called.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Did not notice the const conversion

Comment: @Guss No problem. It's bitten me few times so I understand where you're coming from.

Comment: @Guss fwiw, what you observe is consistent with "normal" overload resolution of methods: https://godbolt.org/z/4GKhGKevW

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes definitly. Thanks for pinpointing this, I totaly forgot that symbol cv qualifier was stronger than argument implicit conversion when deducing the symbol https://godbolt.org/z/Mn7qxnsjY

Comment: @Guss really no need to make excuses :) I found that out only by experimenting and I wouldnt be able to explain you why without reading this answer